# CanvasJS undefined is not an object "none"

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

Downloaded the [Canvasjs Library](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/intro/installation/) and with JSON/PHP got some data out of my Database to portray into a nice Line Chart. All this I did locally (XAMPP).

Now I put my code on the 'live' server and apparently the canvasjs library file canvasjs.min.js has a object that is undefined..

I have tried every single thing but it keeps giving the following error through console (chrome/safari):

error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._toolBar.style')

```
"none" !== this._toolBar.style.display && this._zoomButton && (this.panEnabled ? Z(a, a._zoomButton, "zoom") : Z(a, a._zoomButton, "pan"), a._resetButton.getAttribute("state") !== a._cultureInfo.resetText && Z(a, a._resetButton, "reset"));
```

How can this be? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Canvasjs will create a div called _toolBar in the container div that you specify when you create the new chart. If your HTML document does not contain an element with the id you gave you will get this error.